# Laravel ignore id, on array ? (multiple update)

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation, laravel-5.4

In Laravel, we can do validation on array like

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'users.*.name' => 'bail|nullable|min:2',
    'users.*.username'=>'bail|nullable|min:4|unique:t0101_user,username,' .$xx
    'users.*.password' => 'bail|nullable|min:6'
], $this->messages());
```

In this scenario, what should i passed to the xx ?
I will need something like

```
users.*.id
```

Thank you,
(Laravel version 5.4)

Answer (score -1):

**Laravel Unique Validation Rule**

[Documentation Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique/)

> You need to manually create a validator using the `unique` rule

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

    Validator::make( $data, [
        'users.*.username' => [
            'bail', 'nullable', 'min:4', Rule::unique( 't0101_user', 'username' )->ignore( 'users.*.id' )
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: Did you try this before posting? It doesn't work.